# Case insensitive search of an Excel file using Pandas read_excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I need to get sheets from an Excel file with a certain name. Unfortunately sometimes the sheet names are not formatted correctly ie "Test Sheet" vs "Test sheet". I need a case insestive way of getting these sheets.

```
excel_file= pd.ExcelFile("file_name.xlsx")

sheet_needed = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="Test Sheet") # <- This needs to be case insensitive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So pandas doesnt seem to have a good way of having a case insensitive search, However you can get the sheetnames as a list and pd.read will accept an index for the sheet name so I came up with this to solve the problem

```
excel_file= pd.ExcelFile("file_name.xlsx")
sheet_to_find = "Test Sheet"

# Get all the sheetnames as a list
sheet_names = excel_file.sheet_names

# Format the list of sheet names
sheet_names = [name.lower() for name in sheet_names]

# Get the index that matches our sheet to find
index = sheet_names.index(sheet_to_find.lower())

# Feed this index into pandas
sheet_needed = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make that request case insesitive, but you could try to manipulate the file with openpyxl something like this:

```
import openpyxl

filename = 'file_name.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    ws.title = ws.title.title()    

filename = 'new_'+filename
wb.save(filename)
wb.close()
```

the old title gets replaced with the 'titlelized' name of itself. You could also use the lower() or upper() function of the str object for that.

Comment: Im hoping to not have to open, edit, save and reopen. As this will really hurt the overall speed of the program. 
I do however appreciate this would work in a scenario where I didnt mind this extra overhead.